# How to connect to a SQL database on MacOS with Entity Framework Core and Database First

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core-webapi, workbench, database-first

I have recently changed from Windows to MacOS and I'd like to make a simple project with ASP.NET Core Entity Framework with CRUD operations. I want to use Database First.

So please can someone guide me in the right path, how I can setup an ASP.NET Core Entity Framework with Database First. I been stuck for a few weeks now.

I use Visual Studio and Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so via the dotnet cli, and reverse engineer your database design into EF Core entities. So eg. open terminal and type in the

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server={sql_server_name};Database={database_name};Trusted Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer -o Models
```

breaking the cli command up it would be

`dotnet ef` is the ef core part of the cli 
`dbcontext scaffold` is the name of the command  
`"Server={sql_server_name};Database={database_name};Trusted Connection=True;"` would be your connection string 
so depending on what sql server you are, I would assume it's a mysql with workbench which means you would probably type in a username and password, so instead of *Trusted Connection=True;*  you would provide a *uid={username}* and *pwd={password}*

`Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer` this tells the cli which databaseprovider to use.

`-o Models` is the name of the output folder you want the generated models to be generated in.

with all these things in mind I would suggest you'd try this in the root folder of your project.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server={sql_server_name};database={database_name};uid={db-username};pwd={db-password};" Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer -o Models
```

**Link to the documentation:** 
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx